# Python Convert punycode back to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, sendgrid, punycode

I'm trying to add contacts to *Sendgrid* from a db which occasionally is storing the user email in *punycode* `example-email@xn--yaho-sqa.com` which translates to `example-email@yahóo.com` in Unicode.

Anyway if I try and add the *ascii* version there's an error because *sendgrid* doesn't accept it - however it does accept the Unicode version.

So is there a way to convert them in python.

So I think long story short is there a way to decode *punycode* to Unicode?

**Edit**

As suggested in comments i tried
`'example-email@yahóo.com'.encode('punycode').decode()` which  returns `example-email@yaho.com-cgc` so this is incorrect outside of python so is not a valid solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong on the `punycode` encoding (see reference at [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings))? `'example-email@yahóo.com'.encode('punycode').decode()` returns `example-email@yaho.com-cgc` and vice versa: `'example-email@yaho.com-cgc'.encode().decode('punycode')` -> `example-email@yahóo.com`.

Comment: That does work thanks however it's a different format completely, probably because it's a python specific encoding.  so still leaves the problem of how to get the correct format?

Comment: `xn--yah-sqa.com` isn't a valid Punycode/IDN string. You could verify at [Punycode converter](https://www.punycoder.com/): `yahóo.com` translates to Punycode as `xn--yaho-sqa.com`.

Comment: Yes forgive the typo but this enforces my point that doing it in python is completely different as using the python punycode `email@yahóo.com'.encode('punycode').decode()` returns `example-email@yaho.com-cgc` when really it's `xn--yaho-sqa.com` i'm looking for
Also will edit the original question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is the `xn--` [ACE prefix](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3490.html#section-5) in your encoded e-mail address:

> The ACE prefix for IDNA is "xn--" or any capitalization thereof.

So apply the `idna` encoding (see [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)):

> codec `idna` Implement [RFC 3490](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3490.html), see also [`encodings.idna`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.idna).
> Only errors='strict' is supported.

**Result**:

```
'yahóo.com'.encode('idna').decode()
# 'xn--yaho-sqa.com'
```

and vice versa:

```
'xn--yaho-sqa.com'.encode().decode('idna')
# 'yahóo.com'
```

You could use the [`idna` library](https://pypi.org/project/idna/) instead:

> Support for the Internationalised Domain Names in Applications (IDNA)
> protocol as specified in [RFC 5891](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5891). This is the latest version of
> the protocol and is sometimes referred to as “IDNA 2008”.
>
> This library also provides support for Unicode Technical Standard 46,
> [Unicode IDNA Compatibility Processing](https://unicode.org/reports/tr46/).
>
> **This acts as a suitable replacement for the “[`encodings.idna`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.idna)” module that comes with the Python standard library, but which only
> supports the older superseded IDNA specification ([RFC 3490](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3490.html)).**

Comment: encode('punycode') works even better and supported decode

Comment: @0dminnimda yes, `punycode` works however gives slightly different results: `['yahóo.com'.encode( 'idna').decode(), 'yahóo.com'.encode( 'punycode').decode()]` returns following: `['xn--yaho-sqa.com', 'yaho.com-x3a']`…

Comment: yes, you need to prepped "xn--", or remove the last "-" if the old_text + "-" == new_text. Then there are no symbols to encode.

Comment: At least the built-in "idna" doesn't work as good